# Call Perl within Tcl

Tags: perl, tcl, interaction

Quick question.

How can I call a perl script (using arguments) within tcl and collect output and store it in a variable, which later will be printed out on IRC (using eggdrop).

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in Tcl you would use something like exec or open to do that. See the documentation on exec: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm and open: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm

If you do not want to execute an external perl interpreter you could get the tclperl package and just run it inline, might be faster too:
http://jfontain.free.fr/tclperl.htm
(see this link for the sources: http://jfontain.free.fr/tclperl-3.2.tar.bz2)

Answer (score 3):

simply: `set perl_output [exec perl -lane {perl_script(goes => $here)} file]`